# Material UI & React: ThemeManager is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm adding in Material UI to a small React app but I believe the tutorial I am going through is outdated and they are utilizing an older version of Material UI. I keep getting `_materialUi2.default.Styles.ThemeManager is not a constructor` in the web console as well as `Missing class properties transform`.

The docs for Material UI aren't so great, and I'm not sure if there's a better resource to look at their latest documentation.

I believe the problem is with `ThemeManager.setPalette()`. Any advice?

```
import React from 'react';
import mui from 'material-ui';
import MessageList from './MessageList.jsx';

// Material UI
import ThemeManager from 'material-ui/lib/styles/theme-manager';
import Colors from 'material-ui/lib/styles/colors';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/lib/app-bar';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/lib/styles/getMuiTheme';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    ThemeManager.setPalette({
      primary1Color: Colors.blue500,
      primary2Color: Colors.blue700,
      primary3Color: Colors.blue100,
      accent1Color: Colors.pink400
    });
  }

  static childContextTypes = {
    muitheme: React.PropTypes.object
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      muiTheme: ThemeManager.getMuiTheme()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar title="Chat App"/>
        <MessageList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right the tutorial is outdated. Import it like this:

```
import ThemeManager from 'material-ui/lib/styles/theme-manager';
```

Also: the key passed through context must be called "**muiTheme**"

Check out number 1 on this page of the docs: http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes

Comment: Yeah, I had already added that in (see code above) but I'm not sure what else might be outdated. I was looking at that example, however in it they require in a raw theme file (of their own)...which I'm not sure what would look like.

Comment: //the key passed through context must be called "muiTheme"

Comment: try to make your component as much like the one in the link as possible, I see that one typo above, where you use all lowercase letters in the context

Comment: That was it! Dang typos. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the tutorial is outdated.

Instead of doing this:

```
ThemeManager.setPalette({
      primary1Color: Colors.blue500,
      primary2Color: Colors.blue700,
      primary3Color: Colors.blue100,
      accent1Color: Colors.pink400
    });
```

You can define your theme in a seperate folder like `Theme.jsx`

```
import Colors from 'material-ui/lib/styles/colors';

export default {
  palette: {
     primary1Color: Colors.blue500,
     primary2Color: Colors.blue700,
     primary3Color: Colors.blue100,
     accent1Color: Colors.pink400
  }
};
```

Then in your main `App.jsx`, import `Theme.jsx` and set it to `getMuiTheme(MyTheme)`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MessageList from './MessageList.jsx';

import ThemeManager from 'material-ui/lib/styles/theme-manager';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/lib/app-bar';
import MyTheme from './Theme.jsx';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  static childContextTypes = {
   muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
 }

 getChildContext(){
   return {
     muiTheme: ThemeManager.getMuiTheme(MyTheme)
   };
 }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <AppBar title="Chat App"/>
          <MessageList />
      </div>

    );
  }

}
```

This should solve the problem